# Error was: No module named backends.spatialite.base

Tags: django, sqlite, spatialite

For testing purposes I'm trying to use SQLite, but it seems I'm missing the **spatialite** backend:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django.contrib.gis.backends.spatialite' isn't an available database backend.
Try using django.db.backends.XXX, where XXX is one of:
    'dummy', 'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'sqlite3'
Error was: No module named backends.spatialite.base
```

Any idea how I can make Django find it?

I have [installed spatialite](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/spatialite/).

This is my db setup:

```
DATABASES['default'] = {
    'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.backends.spatialite',
    'NAME': '/tmp/test.db'
}
```

Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS; Python 2.7.3; Django 1.4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look for:

django.contrib.gis.db.backends.spatialite

not

django.contrib.gis.backends.spatialite

:)

trying importing from shell

Comment: great, that seems to work; next problem is `The pysqlite library does not support C extension loading. Both SQLite and pysqlite must be configured to allow the loading of extensions to use SpatiaLite.` which I guess means that I need to manually compile pysqlite.

Comment: fixed, here's how: http://technotes.tumblr.com/post/40838871308/django-with-sqlite-as-a-geospatial-database